# .NET Core MVC set redirect for role authorization failure

Tags: c#, redirect, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been looking for a way to control where the user is redirected to if an authorization fails. I've seen a lot of Stackoverflow topics on this regarding CookieAuthentication and the LoginPath attribute, but I'm not using cookie authentication (see the implementation below).

Is there a way to redirect to a non-authorized page and not just get a 403 error in the browser?

**Current authorization implementation**

*In web.config*

```
<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

*In Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthorization(
        options =>
            options.AddPolicy("FooUsersAndAdmins",
                policy => policy.RequireRole(@"FOODOMAIN\users-group", @"FOODOMAIN\admins-gropu")));                                    
}
```

*Use across different controllers*

```
[Authorize(Policy = "FooUsersAndAdmins")]        
public class HomeController : Controller { ...
```

Comment: You can use `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/errors/{0}")` this will then redirect to **/errors/403** on a 403 response or **/errors/401** on a 401 response and ect.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling#configuring-status-code-pages) with the documentation

Comment: @George Hm, only want to do it on 403, though. This redirects for every single request, right?

Comment: I think if there is no 401 or any status code, it wont redirect to that action. Only actions which exist.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something, then, because just added that line doesn't seem to do much. How do I control what view to display?

Comment: That moment when the one SO question that matches what you need is unanswered...